# Cannot run individual Test Specifictations from the command line

Tags: grails, gradle

When issuing

```
grails test-app PostIntegrationSpec
```

from the command line, I get the following error:

```
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [PostIntegrationSpec]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.115 secs 
| Tests FAILED Test execution failed
```

Tests are there, and they run successfully if I e.g. run them via JUnit from IntelliJ. Also, grails test-app -integration works fine. I figure gradle could have a problem there, but was as now unable to find the issue. Maybe wrong plugins?

I am using an out of the box, grails create-app configuration and have

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it...

```
./gradlew iT --tests *PostIntegration*
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it for me. I would like to understand the issue though

Comment: @thomi If the test is defined under `src/integration-test/groovy` and you really want to use `grails test-app` for some reason, you could do it with `grails test-app -integration PostIntegrationSpec` or `grails test-app -integration PostIntegration`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the package when running tests from the command line:

```
grails test-app com.example.PostIntegrationSpec
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one. But there seems to be something wrong with the gradle command issued